# Intent filter: Handel hashtag sign on pathPattern and pathPrefix

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking, intentfilter, applinks

I need your help to fix a problem with an intent filter that launches the activity after clicking a URI that looks like this https://myapp.com/#/path1/path2. Is there a way to escape hashtag signs when creating a path pattern?
I’ve tried `/\\#/` , `/%23/` and `/.*/` without success.
Is there a way to override the default UriMatcher?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I need your help to fix a problem with an intent filter that launches the activity after clicking a URI that looks like this https://myapp.com/#/path1/pathe2.

My guess is that you would need to create an `<intent-filter>` just with the scheme and host, accepting all paths. You might be able to limit it to just a path of `/` — I have not tried matching only the `/` path of a domain.

> Is there a way to escape hashtag signs when creating a path pattern?

In your example, your path is `/`. `#` is not part of the path. In [URL syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax), `#` represents the separator that precedes the fragment portion of the URL. Your fragment is `/path1/pathe2`. You cannot match on a fragment (or query parameters) in an `<intent-filter>`.

> Is there a way to override the default UriMatcher?

In custom firmware? Yes. In an app? No, because it is not part of your app.